# XAMPP delete and put requests on localhost doesn't work

Tags: apache, laravel, rest

I have this code on a page

```
<td>
  <form method="DatabasePost" action=".../admin/users/1" accept-charset="UTF-8">
      <input name="_method" type="hidden" value="DELETE">
      <input name="_token" type="hidden" value="EMyKLKBmQjBUz63XqSRRqH06Mw0PwzikT5EkJZyc">
      <input type="submit" value="Delete">
  </form>
</td>
```

Generated by Blade in v.4.2. Laravel; yet in browser's Network developer tools I still recieve a GET request. What am I doing wrong? Do I have to enable these requests (delete/put) in Apache or something? I have this

```
<Directory />
AllowOverride All
<Limit GET HEAD POST PUT DELETE OPTIONS>
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from all
</Limit>
```

in apache's httpd.conf and this

```
<Limit GET POST PUT DELETE>
  Allow from all
</Limit>
```

in .htaccess file but nothing seems to work..
On DELETE request @destroy method should be called in Laravel's controller but @show (GET request route) is called instead.

EDIT: 
routes.php

```
Route::resource('admin/users', 'App\Controllers\Admin\UserController');
```

console command `php artisan routes` does in fact show all routes

Comment: Could you show your route file plz

Comment: @HasanTareque edited sorry

Answer (score 0):

Your form should be as follows (assume it is blade file):

```
<form method="post" action="{{url('admin/users/1')}}">
      <input name="_method" type="hidden" value="DELETE">
      <input name="_token" type="hidden" value="{{csrf_token()}}">
      <input type="submit" value="Delete">
  </form>
```

Comment: It was exactly that but instead of "post" in form method it was "DatabasePost" (blade made it that way)... now, when there is just "post" (I used HTML istead of blade - exactly what you posted) I get an MethodNotAllowedHttpException

Comment: When I use <form method="delete"... it says Method [show] does not exist.



When I use <form method="post".. it says MethodNotAllowedHttpException 



When I use <form method="DatabasePost".. (the blade way) it also needs show method